# How do I create a table with a single cell on top?

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create a table like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Tex Stack Exchange. Could you provide the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `\cline{1-1}` instead of `\hline` for the topmost horizontal line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' fixed-width column type

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | wl{3cm} | wl{3cm} | l | }
\cline{1-1}
\textit{Verantwortlicher}     \\ \hline
Name & Vorname & Matrikel-Nr. \\ \hline
     &         &              \\ \hline     
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. `\cline{1-1}` is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` is similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` (of the package `array`) but provides more new functionalities.

In particular, the key `hvlines` will draw all the rules excepted in the *corners* when the key `corners` is used. Here, I use `corners=NE` which means that the corner *north-east* will be automatically computed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{wl{3cm}wl{3cm}l}[hvlines,corners=NE] % NE = north-east
\textit{Verantwortlicher}     \\ 
Name & Vorname & Matrikel-Nr. \\ 
     &         &              \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score -1):

Have a look to the following approach:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Preamble
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Use UTF-8 encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Use modern font encoding

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|ll}
\cline{1-1}
Verantwortlicher & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}                                             \\ \hline
Name             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Vorname} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Matrikel-Nr.} \\ \hline
                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

For beginners, I recommend you to use programs such as https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables. It will make easier to deal with tables.

Comment: You had me until the final paragraph of your answer, in which you recommend using a site such as tablegenerators.com to create LaTeX tables. In particular, I would forcefully disagree with your claim that such sites "make it easier to deal with tables." To the contrary, the needless complexity of the LaTeX code generated by these sites makes the resulting `tabular`-like environments virtually unmaintainable by humans, keeping would-be users from learning sound coding practices from analyzing the code they emit. I would definitely shy away from claiming that such tables are "easy to deal with".

Comment: tablegenerators.com can be helpful for beginners who are not familiar with LaTeX syntax. That is a fact. They can generate code for tables with a few clicks, which can be a good starting point for learning how to create tables in LaTeX. I believe that this is a small price to pay for the convenience they offer. BTW, just because someone has a different approach about how to learn latex does not mean that your answer is wrong or deserves a negative vote.

Comment: For the record: I did *not* downvote your posting. I actually fully agree with your view that disagreeing on substance is no excuse for casting an anonymous downvote. On the code you posted: I do question the usefulness of the 2 instances of `\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}`, *especially* for a learner. This code is only necessary because of the earlier `\begin{tabular}{|l|ll}` declaration. If it had been `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l}`, blank cells would have been fine in row 3. That said, having a substantive discussion is so much more productive than casting an anonmous downvote, isn't it?! :-)